# Invert Number in C#

Tags: c#, math, xna

Is there an easy way to invert a number in C# with a function?
I'm using XNA and i'd like to tell my program that if my 'variable' gets beyond a certain number it has to invert it's value.
The whole point is to give a rebound effect.

```
     if (ballPosition.X >= screenWidth)
                {
                    // Invert the ball Direction Vector.X
                }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just whack a `-` sign in front of it:

```
direction.X = -direction.X;
```

Comment: oh... Didn't know we could do this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Will this work as a double negative?
If direction.X is -5 and I apply 
direction.X = -direction.X;
is direction.X now 5 ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - Yes.  No problem.

Answer (score 10):

or you can try using Vector.X * -1

Comment: Hey this implies an additional calculation.

Comment: It also won't work with long.MinValue, the value still will be negative

Comment: @PawelCioch because it will overflow IIRC